# Having difficulties toggling a class to .active (for a simple accordion style faq)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to toggle the `.accordionQuestions` div to active once the btn element is clicked:

The hidden `.accordionAnswers` div is set to `display: none` on my stylesheet.

Once `.accordionQuestions` is active, `.accordionAnswers` is set to `display: block`.

I've tried looping over the `.btn` using addEventListener, but no luck so far.

I've tried using `parentNode` to access `.accordionQuestion`, and set that to active, but it doesn't seem to work. Any advice is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time!

I'm guessing that the `.accordionQuestions.active` can't access another div `.accordionAnswers`, even though it's in the same div. Os there any other way using toggle?

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')

btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    btn.parentNode.classList.toggle('active')
  })
});
```

```css
.accordionAnswers {
  display: none;
}

.accordionQuestions.active .accordionAnswers {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordionQuestions">
    <h3>How many team members can I invite?</h3>
    <button class="btn"><img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg"/></button>
  </div>
  <div class="accordionAnswers">
    <p>
      You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion active">
  <div class="accordionQuestions">
    <h3>What is the maximum file upload size?</h3>
    <button class="btn"><img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" /></button>
  </div>
  <div class="accordionAnswers">
    <p>
      No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.accordionAnswers` is not a descendant of `.accordionQuestions`, so how should `.accordionQuestions.active .accordionAnswers` target the element with class `accordionQuestions`?

Comment: That's what I thought! How would you rewrite the JS so it can access .accordionQuestions? Would it be more siple to rewrite the HTML instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `.accordionAnswers` is not a child of `.accordionQuestions`, they're siblings. You need to use the `+` operator in your CSS selector:

```css
.accordionQuestions.active + .accordionAnswers {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's a full working example:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')

btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    btn.parentNode.classList.toggle('active')
  })
});
```

```css
.accordionAnswers {
  display: none;
}

.accordionQuestions.active + .accordionAnswers {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordionQuestions">
    <h3>How many team members can I invite?</h3>
    <button class="btn"><img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg"/></button>
  </div>
  <div class="accordionAnswers">
    <p>
      You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion active">
  <div class="accordionQuestions">
    <h3>What is the maximum file upload size?</h3>
    <button class="btn"><img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" /></button>
  </div>
  <div class="accordionAnswers">
    <p>
      No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that totally worked! Thank you so much for taking your time to help out, I was scratching my head for a long time over this issue.